# How to remove space in CarouselView (CarouselView inside ScrollView)

Tags: xamarin

I use CarouselView inside ScrollView because I only want CarouselView to bind Imgae only. More info shows up as I scroll the page. I don't want to Binding other information inside CarouselView because I only want other information to display outside CarouselView.

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
    <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
        <CarouselView IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ProductInfo.ProductImages}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="#fff">
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" Margin="15,0" CornerRadius="7" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                            <control:AspectRatioContainer AspectRatio="1">
                                <Image HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Images}"/>
                            </control:AspectRatioContainer>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <StackLayout Margin="0">
            <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                IndicatorColor="#ddd"
                Margin="0,-100,0,0"
                Padding="0"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="#333"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                IndicatorSize="5"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="15" Margin="0,0,0,5" BackgroundColor="#fff">
        <Label Text="{Binding ProductInfo.Name}" FontFamily="{StaticResource QuicksandBold}" FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#333"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label TextType="Html" Text="{Binding ProductInfo.ContentsSmall}" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontFamily="{StaticResource QuicksandRegular}" FontSize="13" TextColor="#333"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</ScrollView
```

However I want to remove the whitespace below.

[image]

Please help me any solution except setting HeightRequest of CarouselView. Tks!

Comment: Could you share the code of `AspectRatioContainer` ? And why don't you want to set  HeightRequest on CarouselView? It's the quickest solution .

Comment: Yes, code of AspectRatioContainer, You can consult: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhHYwZxO9cY. I don't want to use HeightRequest because I want the CarouselView's height to be auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the image is square , we just need to let the height equal to the width on CarouselView , so we can bind `HeightRequest` with a value(screen width) .

##### Xaml

```
 <CarouselView x:Name="cView" IndicatorView="indicatorView" HeightRequest="{Binding ScreenWidth}">
```

##### Code behind

```
public double ScreenWidth { get; set; }
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
    ScreenWidth = mainDisplayInfo.Width/mainDisplayInfo.Density;
    this.BindingContext = this;
}
```

[image]

Comment: And do I need to declare: ScreenWidth ?. I tried: public double ScreenWidth { get; }. But it doesn't work: Binding ScreenWidth not found

Comment: public double ScreenWidth { get; set; }

Comment: Yes, but I incurred: BindingContext = new ViewProductViewModel();--> I get VM data. So how to Binding ScreenWidth. Do you have any solution?

Comment: You can declare `ScreenWidth` inside the viewmodel , assign the value in viewmodel constructor.